# Access-Control-Allow-Origin: null got detected while I've set value in Nginx and Tomcat

Tags: security, nginx, tomcat, cors

WebInspect has detected the target application supports “Origin: null” for CORS requests, making it vulnerable to CORS attacks. This's a High Issue of the vulnerability scanning report.
I've set the corresponding header value **"Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*.example.com"** in Tomcat's web.xml and Nginx in order to fix this but still got detected as null.
However if check by the browser, the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*.example.com" has shown at the response header, how come the null value still exists in the scanning report? Could this be a false issue?
in nginx.conf:

```
    location /frontend{
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *.example.com
  }
```

browser response header:

```
HTTP/1.1 200
Server: nginx
Date: Mon, 08 Nov 2021 04:05:21 GMT
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Vary: Origin
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Method
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Headers
Last-Modified: Wed, 03 Nov 2021 07:16:34 GMT
ETag: W/"0d4a4d79789d33107032637b2af5c74f1"
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *.example.com
Content-Encoding: gzip
```

[image of scanning report shows “Origin: null”](https://i.stack.imgur.com/khubM.jpg)

Comment: The only wildcard you can specify in the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header is `*`. No browser (except Safari, because it's weird) will accept `*.example.com`. If you need to allow subdomains of `example.com`, you need to validate the request's origin and dynamically generate the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` value.

Comment: I tried using `*`, `http://example.com`, `*.example.com` already, the browser showed response header with all these values on Access-Control-Allow-Origin, only the WebInspect still saying there's null value

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Quick Answer:
place below setting in nginx.conf

```
location /frontend{
    proxy_set_header Origin '*.example.com';
}
```

Explanation:
The scanning report shows how the attacking request had been set, so using Postman to simulate all the request header values and see what nginx actually respond will make things clear.
Turns out with the request header **Origin:null** , the response shows two **Access-Control-Allow-Origin**, one is **null**, the other is ***.example.com**, and the null overrides the `add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *.example.com` setting in nginx.conf, because in the project there's a Spring Configuration that sets `CorsConfigurationSource.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("*"))`, which indicates all the response headers for Access-Control-Allow-Origin would be whatever the request in Origin. Therefore, using `proxy_set_header` redefines Origin in the request header passed to the nginx.